# REmove invalid Characters in Unicode in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to Remove Invalid unicode Characters from a field in sql server.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you count as "invalid" characters?

What is the data-type of the field (char/varchar) or (nchar/nvarchar)

What you may find is that this is an instance where a SQLCLR function to take a SqlString as an input and return a SqlString.

You can then use the more powerful .NET String-manipulation, Encoding,  and Globalization features.